# How to render to qt widgets from another thread the right way?

Tags: multithreading, qt

I want to make a video application that uses ffmpeg for decoding and qt for displaying the frames, the problem for me is how to make it so that application doesn't freeze the video animation when i resize or drag the window. I thought using QOpenglWidget and render to it from a thread, but QOpenglWidget internally uses FBO and still requires that the updates happen on the main thread(documentation says so), and resizing the window will block the frame updates. My question is how to make is so that application doesn't stop updating frames when interacting with the GUI, and i want that the rendering happens on a qt widget.

Comment: I can't provide an answer to your question, other than: "You can't!". The problem is that you put two incompatible conditions: "directlly" and "from a separate thread". You may do it indirectly from another thread, or directly from the main thread.

Comment: I just want that the video doesn't stop updating when im using gui or trying to move or resize the window, i thought rendering directly is the answer. But if there is a right way of doing this im interested in hearing it.

Comment: You may ask another question, without using the word 'directly'.

Comment: I have edited the title od this one

Comment: The right way to paint, draw, render or in any other way modify the visual apperance of a widget is doing it only in the overrided method `paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)`. You can do your decoding in a separate thread, and after each frame is ready, call the `widget->update()` method. This `update()` method signals the main thread to paint the widget asap (using your overrided `paintEvent()`). The problem is reduced to a classic  [producer-consumer synchronization](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-synchronizing.html) problem between two threads, but this is another question.

Comment: The way i understand it calling update function will send update event that gets quequed, and not processed at that moment, so if you do some action that blocks main thread(like resizing or moving window) until the processing of that event is not done, the update event will sit in a queue, and the window will not get updated

Comment: Yes, you understand well that the update method enqueues a paint event. Exactly in the same way that a window resize or move operations will enqueue its paint events without blocking the main thread You should try by yourself and understand for instance how the [2d painting Qt5 example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtopengl-2dpainting-example.html) works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201767/discussion-between-pedro-and-goran).

Comment: Probably too late to help... Use two threads. Each with thier own OpenGL context with shared resources. In the FFMPG thread render into an FBO. In the GUI thread use the FBO texture to draw the video frame. You will need at least two FBO's, one to draw the frame into, while second FBO texture is being used to display the frame in the GUI thread. Swap the FBO's over when the video frame was been drawn by FFMPEG in a thread safe manner.